# Add global NavigationExtras to every navigate action by the router

Tags: angular, angular-router

Is it possible to provide global [`NavigationExtras`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) to the router?

I have to use `skipLocationChange` whenever I navigate to a different page in my app. I currently add this option either in the template:

```html
<a routerLink="settings" skipLocationChange>Settings</a>
```

or in the component:

```ts
this.router.navigate(['settings'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Could I somehow define global default `NavigationExtras` that are automatically added to all `navigate` actions by Angular so that I don't have to add them manually to every link in a template or every call to `router.navigate(..)` in a component?

Answer (score 1):

I've been battling with this for the last hour. Effectively the web app I'm working on is started from a non regular browser (QT based) as an add-in.

And for some reason, as soon as the location history is used, bits of the app stop working (without any error).

I double checked that it was working fine by adding a "skipLocationChange" to one of my router link and it worked. But there's no way I could do that all over the app and forgetting about just one of them would break the app silently, so it's too risky.

I first thought about extending the router and override the `navigate` method to force passing `skipLocationChange: true`.  But once again this is way too risky... There are other methods that could not go through that one (one example is `navigateByUrl`.

So I thought why not completely turn off the whole history (at least any writting). I dug into Angular source code and found out that what modify the browser location history is the `PushState` method defined by `LocationStrategy`. So the only thing we have to do in order to completely turn off the writing to history is define a class that extends one strategy (can be either `PathLocationStrategy` or `HashLocationStrategy`) and override the `pushState` method to keep it empty:

```
class PathLocationStrategyWithoutHistoryState extends PathLocationStrategy { 
  override pushState( ): void {}
}
```

and then at the top of the app in the providers array inject it:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: PathLocationStrategyWithoutHistoryState
  }
],
```