# Prevent Angular routing taking control of the navigation bar

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a widget with angular. the idea is that I can insert it on any of my clients website, surrounded by their own site.

The issue I'm facing now is that angular routing takes control of the navigation bar, and changes the url. is there a way to use angular routing without allowing that behavior?

Also, on the live server angular deploys, I'm unable to pass url parameters without angular removing them instantly.

Should I rebuild my navigation flow without angular routing? I was using it to be able to go back and forth, etc. I just need it to leave the browsers navigation bar alone.

Comment: If you want routing without the routing ... just remove the routing ?

Comment: I think this is something you may whant to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961201